# epoll and set multiple interests at once

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, epoll

Interestingly, I cannot find any discussion on this rather than some
old slides from 2004.

IMHO, the current scheme of `epoll()` usage is begging for something
like `epoll_ctlv()` call. Although this call does not make sense for
typical HTTP web servers, it *does* make sense in a game server where
we are sending same data to multiple clients at once. This does not
seem hard to implement given the fact that `epoll_ctl()` is already there.
Do we have any reason for not having this functionality? Maybe no
optimization window, there?

Answer (score 0):

You would typically only use `epoll_ctl()` to add and remove sockets from the epoll set as clients connect and disconnect, which doesn't happen very often.

Sending the same data to multiple sockets would rather require a version of `send()` (or `write()`) that takes a vector of file descriptors.  The reason *this* hasn't been implemented is probably just because no-one with sufficient interest in it has done so yet (of course, there are lots of subtle issues - what if each destination file descriptor can only successfully write a different number of bytes).